# Word for a person who was once captivated and is now slipping away?

Tags: nouns, metaphors

What is a good word or phrase for a person who was once captivated and is now slipping away?

For example, someone who used to be a loyal happy customer, but visits less and less often. Or someone who was once very in love with their partner, but is slipping away from them.

They are showing signs of being disillusioned or disinterested but it's not yet a lost cause. There is still time to win them back.

Comment: There is [*backslider*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/backslider), although it has religious connotations.

Comment: Disenchantment.

Comment: The sticking point for me is a word choice that has not yet reached the point of no return but is otherwise in the process of "slipping away" from being a dedicated customer or a fully committed lover.  I can think of a couple of words to cover the slipping away bit, but the point of no return element of such a word eludes me.

Comment: Eureka! See below.

Answer (score 1):

**Disaffected** fits your situation, so long as it is appended to "lover" or "customer" rather than, say, "youth".

> **disaffected** *adjective*
>   having lost loyalty or affection for ⇒ *disaffected voters*, ⇒ *He attracts disaffected voters.,* ⇒ *The survey defined disaffected students as those who were regularly
>   noncompliant or challenging.* [(*Collins English Dictionary*)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disaffected)

Although the adjective is most often applied in situations where the loss of affection/loyalty/respect is specifically directed towards authority, it is used in exactly the way you describe:

> [L]ittle countervailing social or economic glue or public rituals or
>   investments work to sustain anyone's commitment to maintain a flagging
>   union. What's more, the fact of lifelong family security and the
>   tolerant sexual norms of *tisese* make it easy for a **disaffected
>   lover** to stray or to just walk away. (Judith Stacey, [*Unhitched:
>   Love, Marriage, and Family Values from West Hollywood to Western
>   China*, 2011](https://books.google.com/books?id=0yPbHrlXbEoC&pg=PA185&dq=%22disaffected%20lover%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFkPH70e3PAhXFSSYKHSoyAQQQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22disaffected%20lover%22&f=false))
>
> Would he accept it? Was he a man who would let a **disaffected lover**
>   go? (Lindsey Davis, [*The Ides of April: A Flavia Albia Mystery*](https://books.google.com/books?id=s2_l3KwGW04C&lpg=PA259&dq=%22disaffected%20lover%22&pg=PA259#v=onepage&q=%22disaffected%20lover%22&f=false),
>   2013)
>
> If the bitterness goes unaddressed, then the **disaffected spouse**
>   will be reluctant to take responsibility for himself or herself—an
>   essential step for reconciliation and successful restoration of love.
>   (Karen Kayser, *[When Love Dies: The Process of Marital
>   Disaffection](https://books.google.com/books?id=zGLw6LRZtRYC&lpg=PA152&dq=%22disaffected%20spouse%22%20reconcile&pg=PA152#v=onepage&q=%22disaffected%20spouse%22%20reconcile&f=false)*, 1993)
>
> It's easy to assume that a customer who has defected is gone forever.
>   In any case, part of you won't want to call up a **disaffected
>   customer** in case they give your ear a hammering over what a rotten
>   company you are. But think about this – there must have been something
>   they liked about you, and they already know you – so if you can put
>   right what went wrong, maybe you can win them back. (Jim Blythe,
>   [*Principles and Practice of Marketing*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2O2GAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA397&dq=disaffected%20customer&pg=PA397#v=onepage&q=disaffected%20customer&f=false), 2013)
>
> Recovery—returning a **disaffected customer** to a state of
>   satisfaction after a service breakdown—has important economic
>   implications for almost all businesses. (Mark P. Pritchard & Jeffrey
>   L. Stinson, [*Leveraging Brands in Sport Business*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4VxtAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA180&dq=disaffected%20customer&pg=PA180#v=onepage&q=disaffected%20customer&f=false), 2013)

This may be slightly stronger than what you want, however; note that in most cases the disaffected party is right up to the edge of that point-of-no-return: there may be time to win them back, but only precious little.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***disenchanted*** (adjective) covers the meaning that you want. Note the emphasis (on `no longer`) in the definition below.

M-W:

> **[disenchanted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disenchanted)**
>   *adjective*
>
> : **no longer** happy or satisfied with something

Answer (score 0):

Here goes. Let's try **disgruntled** as in the following:

1). Although the salon's best customer became **disgruntled** with their service, the new hairstylist has saved the day and Mrs. Slocombe is now a happy bunny once again!

2). Hollywood is abuzz with tittle-tattle concerning Angelina Bowlie, the **disgruntled** wife of Brad Mitt. Tinseltown-insiders predict that she will give her estranged husband one last chance to save the marriage.

**disgruntled:** unhappy, annoyed, and disappointed about something (Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

How about *jaded*?

> Someone who used to be a loyal happy customer, but visits less and
>   less often may be *jaded*
>
> Someone who was once very in love with their partner, but is slipping
>   away from them may be *jaded*.

M-W:

> [*jaded*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaded): feeling or
>   showing a lack of interest and excitement caused by having done or
>   experienced too much of something

A person who is is jaded might show signs of being disillusioned or disinterested but not yet be a lost cause. It's time to mix it up, to reinvigorate the relationship with the customer or partner, to win them back.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was "bored" but even that and Richard's "jaded" have a negative connotation, although much less so that all those "dis-…" words.

Please try "wavering".

Answer (score 0):

How about *distant* or *remote* or *aloof*?

M-W:

> [*distant*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distant): separated in a relationship other than spatial; reserved or aloof in personal relationship
>
> [*remote*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remote): distant in manner
>
> [*aloof*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aloof): at a distance

In each of these cases, the customer or partner is slipping away but is not gone completely: it's still possible to reach them. These words also lack the negative connotations you want to avoid, e.g., they are not *dis-* words. Which word is best depends on the context.